# Using AWS S3 bucket to store media folder

Tags: magento-1.9, media, cdn, aws, cloudfront-cdn

I'm setting up a Magento site on AWS for the first time and want to use a *S3 bucket* with *Cloudfront CDN*.

I want to store the media folder in an s3 bucket so that I can scale out the servers and they will all use the same S3 bucket.  And use the CDN to speed up performance.

I've been doing a some research and it all recommends that I use an extension such a [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cloudfront-cdn.html).

Why would I need to use an extension?  I thought I could simply set the **Base Media URL** to use our bucket URL to my Magento config at **System > Configuration > Web**

[image]

Do you just need to use an extension for the CDN part? i.e. can I use the s3 bucket by simply adding the configuration above?

Comment: i have used  s3 bucket in my magento , i just want to confirm that if my product images is connect with s3 bucket then why it will created all product images in my system server also ? i dont want product images in my system. i also tried to delete all images in mu system serevr but on refresh the page all images is regenerate in my system .

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick look at the extension here are the benefits of using the extension rather than setting up CDN through web urls config. I've removed the marketing stuff...:

> 1. The extension comes with a tool for refreshing the files on the CDN instantaneously. Without our extension, you have to use a tool on
>      the AWS website called "Invalidation Manager" to make the CDN pull
>      updated files from your server. The invalidation manager is very slow
>      and somewhat unreliable. The invalidation manager also only allows you
>      to refresh 3 files every fifteen minutes... so it is quite time
>      consuming to use it.
> 2. It prevents the CDN from being used on Javascript that requires same-origin loading. This is relevant to Javascript that is used for
>      uploading files.

Having said that there also is a **remark concerning S3** for this extension:

> Currently it does not support S3 as the origin.
>
> That being said, it uses your server as the origin in the same way
>   that S3 works.
>
> Basically, the extension caches your files on CloudFront and then
>   serves them directly to your users from CloudFront. Every two hours
>   the extension checks your server for a new version of the files and
>   updates CloudFront accordingly.

Comment: thanks do you think I could use the S3 bucket for the media folder with the web urls?

Comment: Do you need to use S3? S3 is more expensive compared to Cloudfront when it comes to serving higher volumes. Have a look at the Amazon doc for more information to move from S3 to CloudFront: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html. When you are on CloudFront the extension most likely will work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Now, i'm using bellow solusion.

> 1. use s3 to store media file
> 2. use cdn cloudfront point to s3
> 3. Config subdomain (gallery.domain.com) point  to cloudfront via cname record.
> 4. In System > Configuration > Web > BaseUrl: http(s)://gallery.domain.com

(You can use ssl for this subdomain in cloudfront.)

Comment: if I have images already on s3 server then how images name will get for particular product? Means if   i don't upload the image for a particular product then how it will identify which image needs to pull from s3 server ? Could you please explain this somehow?

Comment: You can use s3fs to sync images between webserver and s3

When you add an image to a product (or any image in a media folder), the image will be synchronized to s3.
However, I have only used this solution on a test environment, and have not applied in practice. https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse